# How to transform the uniform() in Python into something similar in R?

Tags: python, r

I have been wanting to know how can I get a line of Python code that uses the uniform() function such as:

```
X_test = uniform(0, 1, size=(test_size, 20))
```

where test size is 1000 observations and 20 predictors, into an R code version. Much appreciated thanks!

Comment: I can't find a duplicate for this. I confess that part of me wants to respond along the same lines as @MauritsEvers' comment ... but another part wants to say *"You're one of today's lucky 10,000."* (https://xkcd.com/1053/). user665997, I suggest that a little targeted research will save you time and snarky comments like mine here; and once you get past this hurdle in learning R, I believe that SO will again be a good resource for learning how to do things in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a function that takes a random sample from a uniform distribution, there is an R function for that:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Uniform.html

Specifically, use the `runif` function to generate n random samples from min to max.

In your case, you could generate a 1000 by 20 matrix of uniform samples using the following code:

```
matrix(runif(test_size * predictors), ncol=predictors)
```

Comment: That help! thanks!